# my drive mappings have all gone away for some reason - i need help to restore them I really want them the same

Tags: fstab, mountpoint

my current fstab:

```
taichi:~:5014> cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
...
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/md126 during installation
UUID=0ab11366-f5f9-4e8c-b288-07ad58f9ec63 /               ext4    noatime,errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/md127 during installation
UUID=af423dc6-3a35-4792-95c8-46fe89261923 none            swap    sw              0       0
taichi:~:5015>
```

current blkid:

```
taichi:~:5013> sudo blkid
/dev/sde1: LABEL="elements" UUID="14444121534372898409" UUID_SUB="4273187584474511650" TYPE="zfs_member" PARTLABEL="zfs-487cc9bdeef8765e" PARTUUID="afdc02f4-6e74-f04e-83e5-9b364b468e67"
/dev/sdf1: LABEL="elements" UUID="14444121534372898409" UUID_SUB="17730318547503947876" TYPE="zfs_member" PARTLABEL="zfs-da896a5c635b328d" PARTUUID="75cb5f89-30a0-8b46-952a-2c7cfc1a03d8"
/dev/sdg1: UUID="aad3a28e-916b-897a-f262-281b2e0cd0f5" UUID_SUB="1dcd17e8-e8b1-41c6-8058-c0330bf4f6aa" LABEL="taichi:0" TYPE="linux_raid_member" PARTUUID="1ffa9974-01"
/dev/sdg2: UUID="26e0976a-3393-5062-9e6f-f1156dd5a73e" UUID_SUB="75aed2cd-295e-ff30-9ece-9bce5cdc23dd" LABEL="taichi:1" TYPE="linux_raid_member" PARTUUID="1ffa9974-02"
/dev/md1: UUID="0ab11366-f5f9-4e8c-b288-07ad58f9ec63" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/md0: UUID="af423dc6-3a35-4792-95c8-46fe89261923" TYPE="swap"
/dev/sdh1: UUID="aad3a28e-916b-897a-f262-281b2e0cd0f5" UUID_SUB="bf06280b-5b58-d6fd-1ebd-4ed2a3c630fb" LABEL="taichi:0" TYPE="linux_raid_member" PARTUUID="2bf5d977-01"
/dev/sdh2: UUID="26e0976a-3393-5062-9e6f-f1156dd5a73e" UUID_SUB="b6086774-c63f-779a-5779-de5ea439d077" LABEL="taichi:1" TYPE="linux_raid_member" PARTUUID="2bf5d977-02"
/dev/sdi1: LABEL="vboxstorage" UUID="6231037397559528102" UUID_SUB="14143719065845459927" TYPE="zfs_member" PARTLABEL="zfs-629f05ac800f1dff" PARTUUID="156fca01-b949-f24a-a556-38c41fb41736"
/dev/sdj1: LABEL="extra" UUID="2601105151947821560" UUID_SUB="14619765225988124989" TYPE="zfs_member" PARTLABEL="zfs" PARTUUID="99381a3d-f8eb-1f43-b538-30df7601c6c9"
/dev/sdk1: LABEL="extra" UUID="2601105151947821560" UUID_SUB="10751491033511755793" TYPE="zfs_member" PARTLABEL="zfs" PARTUUID="ed76c528-593c-914d-abec-c951453e9f0b"
...
(lots of loops - I will load if needed)
...
/dev/sde9: PARTUUID="271ceb5c-ec05-dc4d-8ee5-54ffa8110f6e"
```

```
/dev/sdf9: PARTUUID="c0698e83-9576-384f-ae87-d3b0cefaca24"
/dev/sdi9: PARTUUID="6a93af32-6d70-c847-a836-e3443a377929"
/dev/sdj9: PARTUUID="c6cc0cf1-2e39-6248-8d4d-2a79de523b1c"
/dev/sdk9: PARTUUID="56451289-6b29-794d-8249-d8ae31519cfa"
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have some zfs pools and a linux raid.  Try:

```
sudo zpool import
```

note the name of the pool(s), then for each pool use it as poolname in the following command

```
sudo zpool import poolname
```

This should get some of your filessystems back.  If you are still missing shares then let us know.

Answer (score 0):

sudo zpool import elements

This was the solution - I feel the fool - need to write down zpool info and not do it in the middle of the night

Comment: Glad that you have it sorted.

Comment: I was double confused - I added the pool for this drive to a different server, 3rd pool - months ago (black friday sale) and everything was fine - several reboots - no issues - all of a sudden the pool imported correctly but the mapping didn't work.  I removed the "bad" pool from the fstab and then after reboot - everything was back as before - I would have expected it to die after the first reboot.  Just a strange reaction